# WWW::Mechanize: save_content-encoding-question

Tags: perl, encoding, save, www-mechanize

Is there a way to influence the encoding of the [save_content()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize#%24mech-%3Esave_content%28_%24filename_%29)-method from `WWW::Mechanize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you need to do that, open a file yourself (specifying whatever encoding you want) and print `$mech->content` to it.

Comment: That would be method [`decoded_content`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Message#%24mess-%3Edecoded_content%28_%options_%29) then because we need characters for the encoding IO layer.

Comment: @daxim: No, you're thinking about [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Response).  WWW::Mechanize decodes the content automatically; it has no `decoded_content` method.

Answer (score 0):

or I could write it this way

```
open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf-8)', $file_name or die $!; 
my $res = $mech->get( $url, ':content_cb' => sub{ print $fh shift } );
```